# How to execute imagemagick with a string as input for filenames - in bash

Tags: linux, bash, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am trying to write a code to do the below.

1: Get all the directory names from input line into a string (Number of directory inputs could vary)

2: For all the tiff files in those directories montage the images (using imagemagick) with the same names and save it in the main folder or given folder.

I want to combine two or more images (depending on the number of directories in the command line input). Each directory has image outputs with same name to the other directory. I wanna combine files with the same names from given directories

The code I wrote is below but its not passing $name as variable to montage command.
What am I doing wrong here? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
for arg in "$@"; do # 
n1=$arg
fname+=$n1"\${name} " #Get all the directory names in a string with $name at the end. for eg: Baseline/$name
done
echo $fname

for n in $arg/*.tif; do
name="$(basename "$n")"
name1=$(echo "$name" | cut -f 1 -d '.')
montage -tile 3x3 $fname name1.png
exit
done
```

More Details[image: Example]

Comment: It's really not very clear what you are trying to do! Maybe you can show some filenames in some directories and say which ones you want to montage?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I have added an image. Hopefully that helps. Thank you!

Comment: Ok, I see what you are actually trying to do now! My answer is not correct for that, so I'll delete it for now and work on correcting it and then undelete it if/when I get a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

Thank you for the clarification, you can do what you want if you save the following as `monty.sh` and make it executable with:

```
chmod +x monty.sh
```

Here's the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Goto first subdirectory and take it off args list
cd "$1"
shift

# Grab remaining directory names into array
friends=( "$@" )
>$2 echo "DEBUG: friends=${friends[@]}" 

# Iterate over files in first directory
for this in *.tiff ; do
   >&2 echo "DEBUG: this=$this"
   # Generate list of files to montage
   { 
      # ... starting with this one...
      echo "$this"
      # ... and adding in his friends
      for friend in "${friends[@]}" ; do
         next="../${friend}/${this}"
         >&2 echo "DEBUG: next=$next"
         if [ -f "$next" ] ; then
             echo "$next"
         else
             >&2 echo "ERROR: file $next is missing"
         fi
      done
    } | magick montage -tile 3x @- ../"${this/tiff/png}"
done
```

Then your command will be:

```
./monty.sh Output1 Output2 Output3
```

or, more succinctly:

```
./monty.sh Output{1,2,3}
```

---

In case you are unfamiliar with `bash` syntax, the code in the middle of the `for` loop is essentially doing:

```
...
...
{ 
   echo first filename to montage onto stdout
   echo second filename to montage onto stdout
   echo third filename to montage onto stdout
} | magick montage <ALL FILENAMES ON STDIN> result.png
```

So it is important that all error messages inside `{...}` are sent to `stderr` else the error messages will go to the `montage` command which will interpret them as filenames. That's why all the debug statements start with `>&2 echo ...` because that directs them to `stderr` so they don't get mixed up with `stdout`.

---

**Original Answer**

I don't understand what you are trying to do, but if you can write all the filenames into **ImageMagick**'s `stdin`, you can make it montage them like this:

```
find . -name "*.tif" -print | magick montage -geometry +0+0 -tile x3 @- result.png
```

Comment: Thanks @MarkSetchell. This code would combine/montage all the images in one folder, If I understood it correctly. I want to combine two or more images (depending on the number of directories in the command line input). Each directory has image outputs with same name to the other directory. I wanna combine files with the same names from given directories

Comment: I think it does what you want now - please take another look.

Comment: Thank you! This is working great! some of the filenames have space in them. I tried putting $this in double quotes and it didnt work. I think spaces are a problem for montage? Also added "-mode concatenate" for more quality. magick montage -mode concatenate -tile 3x @- ../"${this/tif/png}"

Comment: It's late here. I'll work it out tomorrow unless you find it before me...

Comment: As a very quick fix, you could replace `echo "$this"` with `magick "$this" miff:-` and `echo "$next"` with `magick "$next" miff:-` Then at the end use `magick montage -tile x3 miff:- ...`

Comment: Perfect! that worked.